# InvocationTargetException and NullPointerException JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I am using SceneBuilder to create a GUI to get information from the user via text feilds. I get this `InvocationTargetException` and stack trace when I click the calcPremiumButton button.

```
> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PremiumCalculator.calculatePremiumAction(PremiumCalculator.java:52)
    ... 41 more
```

I have traced the `NullPointerException` back to the `setOnMouseClicked` method.

```
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javafx.event.Event;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

    /*** PremiumCalculator ***/
    public class PremiumCalculator extends LifeInsurancePolicy
    {   
       @FXML
       private static TextField coverage;

      @FXML
      private static TextField number;

      @FXML
      private static TextField lName;

      @FXML
      private static TextField a;

      @FXML
      private static TextField fName;

      @FXML
      private static TextField s;

      @FXML
      private static TextField pName;

      @FXML
      private static Label outputLabel;

      @FXML
      private static Button calcPremiumButton;

      @FXML
      private static TextField w;

      @FXML
      private static TextField h;

      @FXML
      private void calculatePremiumAction()
      {
          /*** setOnMouseClicked ***/     
          PremiumCalculator.calcPremiumButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
          {
             /*** handle ***/
             public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
             {
                /*** Get information from the GUI text boxes ***/
                String number = PremiumCalculator.number.getText();
                String pName = PremiumCalculator.pName.getText();
                String fName = PremiumCalculator.fName.getText();
                String lName = PremiumCalculator.lName.getText();
                String a = PremiumCalculator.a.getText();
                String s = PremiumCalculator.s.getText();
                String h = PremiumCalculator.h.getText();
                String w = PremiumCalculator.w.getText();
                String coverage = PremiumCalculator.coverage.getText();

                /*** Convert Strings ***/
                int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                int ag = Integer.parseInt(a);
                double he = Double.parseDouble(h);
                double we = Double.parseDouble(w);
                double c = Double.parseDouble(coverage);
                double lifeInsurance = Double.parseDouble(lifeInsurancePolicyString);

                /*** Instantiate a new LifeInsurancePolicy object ***/
                LifeInsurancePolicy customer = new LifeInsurancePolicy(num, pName, fName, lName, ag, s, he, we);

                /*** Call an instance of the LifeInsurancePolicy object to get the life insurance cost ***/
                double lifeInsuranceAmount = customer.calculateLifeInsurance(s, bmi);

                /*** Display the life insurance cost ***/
                outputLabel.setText("Life Insurance Cost: " + lifeInsuranceAmount);
             }   
             /*** End handle ***/
          });
          /*** End setOnMouseClicked ***/        
       }                
    }
    /*** End PremiumCalculator ***/
```

I am not sure if I am getting the exception because of the `setOnMouseClicked` method or if it is caused by something else. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why `import java.awt.*;`? You shouldn't do this in a class that is used with javafx. *If* you need classes from `java.awt`, import them one by one.

Comment: @fabian I was using something else and didn't take away the import statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SceneBuilder allows someone to edit FXML files. Those files describe a view, an interface, just like a HTML file would do it for a web page.

The problem is that you are trying to put an Event on your button inside the function `private void calculatePremiumAction()`.
But this function is already an Event function (because it has @FXML on top of it), you just have to bind it with your button in SceneBuilder.

[Here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-event-handling-examples/) an example of how you should do it.

Comment: Then you should just write the code you want to be done in the function `calculatePremiumAction()` BUT you have to get rid of the `setOnMouseClicked` and the event-handling part in the code. Only keep what is inside the `handle()` function.

Comment: Okay, so I took out the code as you suggested and I'm getting error messages saying that a semicolon is expected after `public void handle(ActionEvent event)`

Comment: As A.V. suggested, get rid of `public void handle(ActionEvent event)`, you only need the code *inside* the handle function as the body of your `calculatePremiumAction` method.

Answer (score 1):

First make your life easier with [SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/). It will create FXML for you.

Secondly use SceneBuilder's 'On Action' field in code section to name button's handling method in controller directly without clumsy `setOnMouseClicked()` call with anonymous class as parameter. It should look like this in FXML:

```
<Button onAction="#onBtnClicked" text="Text on button" />
```

In controller:

```
@FXML
void onBtnClicked(ActionEvent event) {
   // your handling code goes here
}
```

Then the [FXMLLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html) may be used to load your javaFx `Node` from *.fxml and to inject all `@FXML` annotated fields into instance of your UI controller.

```
URL fxmlLocation = new URL("url to your fxml");
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlLocation);
PremiumCalculator controller = new PremiumCalculator();
loader.setController(controller);
// now load and inject  
Node javafxNode = loader.load();
```

Add `javafxNode` to your scene to make it part of visible scene graph. This should do the trick. Plus your code in controller will be way simpler and easier to understood.